# Best way to calibrate my camera?

Tags: camera

I really didn't notice ubuntu's calibration option ever since i was used with Precise Pangolin.

But what's the best way to calibrate my camera?

Comment: What camera is in question, and what brand, and model?

Comment: @Mitch It's a Azurewave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what to say if is the best way or not, but I used for calibration this small tool: [luvcview - USB Video Class grabber [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/luvcview/)(it doesn't matter if your camera is not on USB).

After you have installed luvcview, run it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) with these options:

```
luvcview -f yuv -l
```

See `man luvcview` for more options.

Comment: Update: **luvcview** has disappeared without a trace. It's not listed in any repository including PPA ones. Even its website is down. Ubuntu uses **guvcview** instead. See `https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=750600`.