# How to check the working condition of my webcam

Tags: webcam

Cheese web cam booth is showing "no Divice Found". I have to understand - is the program is at fault or web cam itself.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300411/best-way-to-calibrate-my-camera/300445#300445).

Answer (score 2):

You can check by typing: `lsusb` into the terminal window (opened using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) it will list your hardware components and usually one of the options should be labeled as the webcam. If it doesn't show up then your webcam isn't being detected by Ubuntu.

As an example you might have something like this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ca:1870 Ricoh Co., Ltd Webcam 1000
```

Though on another laptop I had the webcam detected but it didn't have `Webcam` next to it so you may need to check through the list what each component is (you'll have audio etc there too).

Comment: thank you for immediate response. Checked with the above option and there was no web cam or something alike mentioned. But the camera was working fine till 3 days back! Can you please tell me installing the web cam on the DELL.

Comment: You're more than welcome, its what the site is for ;) Though you'll have to edit your question and add the model name of your Dell laptop. Could you also add the output of `lsusb` to your question :)

Comment: My camera is working but I don't have anything saying "webcam" or "camera" or anything like that. There are lots of devices which could be the camera though, not sure which.